# OS - BOX - How to retrieves the files/folders which is not already fetched?

Tags: ios, box-api

I have fetched the files/folder using folder/{id}/content service. I can fetch the first 100 values initially. 
In next time , I will send the offset value to the same request, it returns the remaining the files/folders.It works.

But, whenever I am doing the refresh in tableview, I want to fetch only new files/folders from the box server. Is it possible to do this?

Is it possible to order files/folder using date(order_by) ?like https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/0/items?fields=name,description,created_at,id&order_by=date&direction=DEC

Answer (score 0):

> In next time , I will send the offset value to the same request, it returns the remaining the files/folders.It works.

No, it is not possible.

Alternative to this is to listen on events stream endpoint, but it only makes sense for desktop /laptop clients where battery drain is not a concern.